# Putting views with a viewPager in the same xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, so forgive me if my asking way or my English aren't good.
I have **imageView** and **textView**, they are in the same `XML`file with my **viewPager**.
 But they didn't appear on my screen because of the **viewPager**.
So How to appear them on my screen ?

This is my XML file 
(Forgive me too because I'm in the entry level in android)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"/>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativ"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.example.ahmed.testteams.MainActivity">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/spain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/spain" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spain"
                android:background="@color/name_league"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/spain_linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spain"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
            <!--  <fragment android:name="com.example.ahmed.testteams.SpanishLeagueFragment"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/spain"
                  android:id="@+id/spain_linear"

                  /> -->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/england"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spain_linear"
                android:src="@drawable/england" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spain_linear"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/england"
                android:background="@color/name_league"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/england_linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/england"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/german"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/england_linear"
                android:src="@drawable/germany" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/england_linear"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/german"
                android:background="@color/name_league"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/germany_linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/german"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/italy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/germany_linear"
                android:src="@drawable/italy" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/germany_linear"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/italy"
                android:background="@color/name_league"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/italy_linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/italy"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: show your XML. There is likely some problem with it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I edited my question with the code .

Comment: `android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"` means that you want the view to take **whole screen**, and no to leave any space for other views. That's exactly what you observe. Please pass through some basic android training cources before you continue to elliminate 100 more questions like this.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thank you for your advice but I know this concept well . I changed it to wrap_content but still other views didn't appear .

Comment: probably becuae the views, that you have placed inside ViewPager are taking as much space as possible (whole screen). It is quite weird to place child views inside viewPager. Do you know how it works? What do you want to achieve withit?

Comment: First try to understand me because my English isn't good :) , in the activity_main.xml  all this LinearLayouts I pass their IDs to MainActivity to their fragments . So I want to show my fragment inside the linearlayout . Instead of  every single page appears a fragment . I don't want that . I want to show my fragment inside this linearlayout . I hope you understand me :) :)